# purpose of timestamp in recaptcha's validate response

Tags: recaptcha

based on the documentation the validation response looks like this

```
{
  "success": true|false,
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
```

I wonder whats the purpose of the timestamp field in the response. Do I need to validate it?

I assume each validation token can only be used once and they expire after some time. So I shouldn't have to worry about the token reuse problem. I can't think of any exploit one could do even if the token doesn't expire at all.

The same goes with hostname. Since the site-key and site-secret must match so I shouldn't have to validate that field either.

Do they exist only for the purpose of logging?